# Export a DB2 schema in human-readable format through command-line?

Tags: windows, db2, db2-luw

Unfortunately `db2backup` and `db2look` are not available to me.

Is there a way to export a schema in DB2 into a human-readable file through command-line (Table DDL/DML with CLOB/BLOB, Views, Aliases, Triggers, etc), and later use the same file for import?

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented routine you can use for this using DB2 CLP, for example, or any other tool, which is able to call routines with `OUT` parameters.

```
db2 "call SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL('-a -e -td @', ?)"
```

The 1-st parameter accepts almost all the same parameters as the `db2look` utility.
The call above returns some `X` value in the 2-nd output parameter (`OP_TOKEN`), which you can use to get the corresponding sql statements generated:

> select sql_stmt
>   from systools.db2look_info_v
>   where op_token=`X`
>   order by creation_time, op_sequence;